# Cloud Functions for Firebase - functions.database.instance (and InstanceBuilder) not found

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add listeners in my cloud functions to a second database instance according to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) using:

```
exports.myHandler = functions.database.instance('foo').ref('bar')...
```

I am getting an error that the `functions.database.instance()` function doesn't exist. I have updated my functions using `npm upgrade` and firebase-functions specifically using `npm install --save firebase-functions`. I still don't see any reference to `InstanceBuilder` or `functions.database.instance()` in the source code. Has this functionality actually been released? Am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly what version of the firebase-functions module are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the dependencies in package.json to use the latest versions of firebase-admin and firebase-functions, and it's fixed.